# Angular 2 Test gets error

Tags: testing, angular

I have a Angular 2 component which is work fine but when I run this code `ng test` to pass all tests I get the followind error message :

```
 Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'mdl-textfield'.                                                                           
    1. If 'mdl-textfield' is an Angular component and it has 'ngModel' input, then verify that it is part of this module.                                 
    2. If 'mdl-textfield' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schema' of this component to suppress this message.      
     ("ditedIndex !== i">{{role.name}}</span>                                                                                                             
                        <mdl-textfield *ngIf="editedIndex === i" [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="roles[i].name" class="full-width" value={{role.name}}></mdl-textfi
```

eld>

here is my HTML :

```
<tr *ngFor="let role of roles; let i = index;" (click)="doSelect(role, i)">
            <td class="table-id">{{ i + 1 }}</td>
            <td>
                <span *ngIf="editedIndex !== i">{{role.name}}</span>
                <mdl-textfield *ngIf="editedIndex === i" [(ngModel)]="role.name" class="full-width" value={{role.name}}></mdl-textfield>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span *ngIf="editedIndex !== i">{{role.description}}</span>
                <mdl-textfield *ngIf="editedIndex === i" [(ngModel)]="role.description" class="full-width" value={{role.description}}></mdl-textfield>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button *ngIf="editedIndex === i" mdl-button mdl-button-type="mini-fab" mdl-colored="primary" (click)="doSave($event)"
                    mdl-ripple><mdl-icon>edit</mdl-icon></button>
                <button *ngIf="editedIndex === i" mdl-button mdl-button-type="mini-fab" mdl-colored="accent" (click)="doDelete($event, i)"
                    mdl-ripple><mdl-icon>remove</mdl-icon></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Role is a model with 2 properties.

Why it works fine in runtime but it's failed in test!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because I am using custom components, I found that I have to import CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA to app.component.spec.ts

```
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';
```

and use it on schemas

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    MdlModule,
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure the test bed with any required modules/component/etc. The only thing you get for free is the `CommonModule`. Everything else, you need to configure from scratch. This means adding the `FormsModule`, and whatever module (component/directive/etc) is used for MDL

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    AnyMDLModule
  ],
  declarations: [],
  providers: []
})
```